# Updating Word 2007/2010 templates

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, templates

If I make a template, then create a document based on it, and then change the template, the document is unchanged. Even if I after changing the template change the document and save it anew, the document is still based on the old template.

If I check automatically update document styles in the templates and plugins window, this does not change spacing in the document. How do I make it update according to the new version of the template? In our case, the template has a large part locked down. If I change the spacing between the nth and (n+1)th editable area in the template, how can I have that reflected in new documents based on documents made with the older version of the template?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, templates don't work like that. They copy the settings when the document is created and later changes to the template only affect new documents created with the new template.